# How to know the effective input domain of special function in SciPy or GSL?

Tags: math, scipy, floating-point, gsl, numerical

I need to know the effective input domain of special functions in SciPy [(Link to special functions of SciPy)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html) or GSL[(Link to special functions of GSL)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/specfunc.html?highlight=special#). For example, for the function *gamma*, the effective input domain is around [-168,168], for input out of the interval *gamma* will return an exception.

I do this job by reading the code of those special function so far. The work would be much harder if a special function has two or three inputs (e.g. gsl_sf_hyperg_2F1(a,b,c,d) has four inputs). So there is any way to know the effective input domain of special functions in SciPy or GSL easier?

Comment: how do you know [-168,168] is the domain of Gamma function?

Comment: The domain is not exactly right, for example, the -2 cannot be calculated by gamma, I found the domain just by reading the code and output of the function. For example, if you give 171 to the gamma, it will return 7.25741561531e+306 which close to the maximum of 64-bit float point, and give 172 will return "inf" means out the domain of 64-bit float point. So I estimate the domain should around [-168,168] for safe.